# Gaussian coefficients identity

Tags: co.combinatorics, coding-theory, q-analogs, mobius-inversion

I am having difficulty showing the equivalence between (11) and (15) of [Delsarte - Association schemes and $t$-designs in regular semilattices](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0097316576900170). It is somehow an application of Möbius inversion, but I can't get it in the right form to make this apparent.

To restate the question:
show
$$
\sum_{j=0}^r {r \choose j}_q M(j,r) \pi(j,r,s) = {m-r \choose m-s}_q {v-s-r \choose v-m-r}_q q^{r(m-s)},$$
where $M(j,r) =(-1)^{r-j} q^{r-j \choose 2}$ is the Möbius function and
$\pi(j,r,s) = \sum_{i=0}^j {j \choose i}_q {m-j \choose s-i}_q q^{(j-i)(s-i)} {v-r-s+i \choose v-m}_q$.

We can treat $v$, $m$, and $s$ as constant integers with $v\geq m \geq s$.
$q$ is a power of a prime that is the order of a field and is a parameter for the Gaussian coefficients.

I have tried switching the order of summation and looking for ways to view this as convolution with the Möbius function. Reference [4] from Delsarte's paper (Delsarte - Association schemes in certain lattices) does not exist.

Comment: I have verified some cases on the computer, and it seems true, but we need m <= v/2 or else it's false. Take q=2, r=3, s=4, v=6, m=5. Then the lhs is -12, while rhs is 0.